# Selectize dropdown within slickgrid is hidden beyond slick grid boundary. How can I make it to come up at top?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid, selectize.js

I am using [selectize](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js) to provide inline cell editing in slickgrid. I am able to load this component within cell. But when dropdown options container pops up and it goes beyond the slickgrid viewport, dropdown options container is getting truncated by slickgrid boundary. It should come over the grid. How can I bring the dropdown options container to the top.

```
var grid;
var columns = [
  { id: 'title', name: 'Title', field: 'title' },
  { id: 'duration', name: 'Duration', field: 'duration' },
  { id: '%', name: '% Complete', field: 'percentComplete' },
  { id: 'start', name: 'Start', field: 'start' },
  { id: 'finish', name: 'Finish', field: 'finish' },
  {
    id: 'effort-driven',
    name: 'Effort Driven',
    field: 'effortDriven',
    editor: IEditor
  },
];

var options = {
  enableCellNavigation: true,
  enableColumnReorder: false,
  editable: true,
  autoHeight: true
};

function IEditor(args) {
  var selectElement = $('<input type="text"/>');
  args.container.append(selectElement[0]);
  selectElement.selectize({
    create: false,
    maxElements: 1,
    options: [
      {
        name: 'A',
        value: 'a'
      },
      {
        name: 'B',
        value: 'b'
      },
      {
        name: 'C',
        value: 'c'
      },
      {
        name: 'D',
        value: 'd'
      },
      {
        name: 'E',
        value: 'e'
      },
      {
        name: 'F',
        value: 'f'
      },
    ],
    labelField: 'name',
    valueField: 'value'
  });

  /*********** REQUIRED METHODS ***********/

  this.destroy = function() {
    // remove all data, events & dom elements created in the constructor
  };

  this.focus = function() {
    // set the focus on the main input control (if any)
  };

  this.isValueChanged = function() {
    // return true if the value(s) being edited by the user has/have been changed
    return false;
  };

  this.serializeValue = function() {
    return '';
  };

  this.loadValue = function(item) {
  };

  this.applyValue = function(item, state) {
  };

  this.validate = function() {
    return { valid: false, msg: 'This field is required' };
  };
}

$(function() {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    data[i] = {
      title: 'Task ' + i,
      duration: '5 days',
      percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      start: '01/01/2009',
      finish: '01/05/2009',
      effortDriven: i % 5 == 0,
    };
  }

  grid = new Slick.Grid('#myGrid', data, columns, options);
  grid.init();
});
```

I have added selectize drop down in Effort Driven column in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hGEFyOoWs02esghUPTao)

Answer (score 1):

I used to use `chosen` as my enhanced select but I ran into exactly this problem, and it wasn't solvable due to the HTML it used.
I had to jump ship to [Select2](https://select2.org). There are examples for this [here](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples) - check out 'Select2 javascript drop-down editor' and 'Select2 Multiselect javascript drop-down editor'.

Comment: Note that the issue was that Chosen used a dropdown element that was inserted into the DOM at the same point as the underlying SELECT element. Because of this, it was always inside the Grid container box, which I found prevented it from overlapping the container bounds. Select2 uses a dropdown element that is absolutely positioned and is added to the DOM in the page footer. Because of this, it can always be positioned independently from the grid in x,y and z location.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your z-index is bigger than the ones SlickGrid uses. If I remember correctly SlickGrid's highest one was 11 or 12, so with a 13 you should be good to go. Also check the overflow of the cells' css classes; it might happen that your context menu is simply cut off.